# JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list - how to properly escape js in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am in trouble to escape this js function in php file:
it returns error: 
JavaScript: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 
The code is this:

```
echo "<a href=\"\" onClick=\"show_confirmation('",$messages['deleting_message'],"', '",$messages['close'],"', 'show_hide('confirmation');', '",$lang['delete'],"', 'redirect_communicator('",$fullurl,"');'); return false;\">Delete</a>";
```

Basically this is js function with 5 parameters and some of them are also functions and there is the problem. all variables like $messages[] are language defined variables.. The error shows the last parameter - function redirect_communicator()

Can you tell me what is wrong and how to escape it? 
Thank you for any suggestions

EDIT:
I also tried this:

```
<a href="" onClick="show_confirmation('<?php echo $messages['deleting_message'];?>', '<?php echo $messages['close'];?>', show_hide('confirmation');, '<?php echo $lang['delete'];?>', redirect_communicator('sda');) return false;">delete</a>
```

and still the same error.. When I add json_encode another error raisen..

Comment: http://php.net/json_encode  **NEVER** dump text from php into a javascript context without json_encode.

Comment: thet's a good point but after I added json_encode() to all php variables I am getting another error: unterminated string in show_confirmation

Comment: then look at your generated page, and fix the syntax errors. you're using php to generate html+js, and you have to make sure that PHP's outputting things CORRECTLY for the context it's being output into.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing languages like this is always hard to read, and rarely a good idea.

However if you need to do it, you can use `sprintf` to help clarify it a little:

```
echo sprintf(
    "<a href=\"\" onClick=\"show_confirmation('%s', '%s', show_hide('confirmation'), '%s', redirect_communicator('%s')); return false;\">Delete</a>",
    $messages['deleting_message'],
    $messages['close'],
    $lang['delete'],
    $fullurl
);
```